# exibir lista de itens com retorno no formato json com php e mysql

Tags: php, json, mysqli

estou desenvolvendo um site para uma imobiliária, no momento estou listando os imóveis e paginando o resultado com consultas sql, são listados mais de 2000 imóveis e há uma demora significativa no carregamento do conteúdo. Estou pensando em retornar o resultado da consulta sql no formato JSON com uma requisição AJAX e listar o conteúdo com Jquery.

Quais as vantagens e desvantagens de usar esse padrão?
Terei performance no carregamento do conteúdo?
É aconselhável usar requisições AJAX que retorne grande quantidade de conteúdo no formato JSON?

Comment: Não é melhor paginar a consulta?

Comment: Já existe a paginação, porém o conteúdo é exibido com consulta direto no sql, quero retornar o resultado no formato json.

Comment: Tem como colocar o código que retorna essa consulta? vc faz algum processamento ou formatação no retorno?

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta.

Comment: Você terá um processamento um pouco maior pois será necessário pegar o array de valores retornado do banco e aplicar um json_encode, porém, acredito que não seja nada muito significativo não. Porém, a demora vai depender do seu algoritmo de retorno.

Comment: Será melhor eu já retornar o html no ajax inserir o html dinamicamente? Nesse caso eu faço uma consulta gero o html com echo, e no ajax informo o dataType: html. Dessa forma consigo um desempenho melhor do que retornar json?